# How to properly resolve multiple factories using Angularjs' UI.Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) this successfully directs me to the proper view and properly retrieves the data from my factory:

```
.state('calendar', {
    url: '/calendar',
    templateUrl: 'templates/calendar.html',
    controller: 'calendarCtrl',
    resolve: { 
        workoutData: ['WorkoutData', function(WorkoutData){ // USING A FACTORY (workoutDataFct.js)
            return WorkoutData.get();
        }]
    }
})
```

but I now want to pull in data from another factory but I can't seem to just add a new factory like this:

```
    resolve: { 
        workoutData: ['WorkoutData', function(WorkoutData){
            return WorkoutData.get();
        }],
        exercises: ['Exercises', function(Exercises){ // USING FACTORY (exercisesFct.js)
            return Exercises.get();
        }]
    }
```

My factory, `exerciseFct.js`, is included in my `index.html` just like `workoutDataFct.js` and I included the `exercises` the dependency in my controller `calendarCtrl` just like I added the `workoutData` dependency. (am I forgetting to do something?)

I don't get and console errors and but I am not routed to the calendar view. This makes me think that the `resolve:` is failing. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: use $q.all to wait for all resource promises to resolve.http://embed.plnkr.co/LZad4ZyEYjrbKiTPbAwu/preview

Comment: If you check the network requests are the workout data and exercise requests both completing successfully?

Comment: @J-D You can use an object with `resolve` as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/NMXazDpEEBMg8mFGUZdw?p=preview

Comment: I am handling  this by using oc lazy loading and ui.load module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things clear here are the available options in your case.

**Option 1:**

Wait for all promises to finish with $q.all.

```
    resolve: {
        delayedData: function($q, WorkoutData, Exercises) {

            var WorkoutData = WorkoutData.get();
            var Exercises = Exercises.get();

            WorkoutData.$promise.then(function(response) {console.log('Resource 1 data loaded!')});
            Exercises.$promise.then(function(response) {console.log('Resource 2 data loaded!')});

            return $q.all([WorkoutData.$promise, Exercises.$promise]);
        }
    }
```

Working example can be found [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/LZad4ZyEYjrbKiTPbAwu/preview).

**Option 2:**

As @ExplosionPills stated use object with resolve.

```
    resolve: {
                WorkoutData: ["WorkoutData", function (Gists) {
                  var WorkoutData = WorkoutData.get();
                  WorkoutData.$promise.then(function(response) {console.log('Resource 1 data loaded!')});
                }],
                Exercises: ["Exercises", function (Meta) {
                  var Exercises = Exercises.get();
                  Exercises.$promise.then(function(response) {console.log('Resource 2 data loaded!')});
                }]
            }
```

Working example can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMXazDpEEBMg8mFGUZdw?p=preview).

Thanks @Explosion Pills for your inputs.

Comment: second one doesn't return anything in either resolve. Go to second page and data is not there in view